# Multiple instances of solution explorer in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, solution-explorer

I have UltraMon installed and quite like it but I would also find it a much better experience if I could also have another instance of Solution Explorer open in the second monitor open on the assembly/namespace/project I have open in that monitor.

However Solution Explorer seems to be Singleton component. Any workarounds?

Comment: No.  Use connect.microsoft.com to file feature requests.

Comment: @HansPassant Actually feature requests are now on [User Voice](http://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Install the [*Productivity Power Tools*](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/d0d33361-18e2-46c0-8ff2-4adea1e34fef/) to use "Solution Navigator" which can have multiple instances – think of it as a prototype for the VS11 Solution Explorer (which also has multiple instances)

(Additional) To open a new instance use the first button on the Solution Navigator toolbar:

[image: Solution Navigator Toolbar: right end]

Comment: Ok I've installed PPT but I cant see how to open multiple instances of Navigator. Seems to have the same behavior as Solution Explorer in this regard. What do I need to do, hold down the shift key or something? Thanks

Comment: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudio/archive/2010/07/20/solution-navigator-blog-post.aspx 

Click the new window button on the tool itself.

Answer (score 2):

You can't open second 'Solution Explorer'. Its a 'named' singleton.

Comment: What's a "named" Singleton? Not familiar with that term.

Comment: on Visual Studio 2010 and earlier versions "Solutions Explorer" etc. toolboxes are named variables hence its not possible to have their multiple instances on a same Visual Studio process